# Rails 5 - Set time to 10th of current month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I define a variable the easiest/nicest way to e.g. 10th of current month?

I have several ways, such as `beginning_of_month + 9.days`.

Also I might want to set it to the 10th of last month, so I could do `prev_month.beginning_of_month + 9.days`.

But I was hoping to find a native function for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [days_since](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-days_since):

```
2.4.0 :001 > Date.today.beginning_of_month
 => Sat, 01 Apr 2017 
2.4.0 :004 > Date.today.beginning_of_month.days_since(9)
 => Mon, 10 Apr 2017
```